# Is this a data race? OPENMP

Tags: c++, openmp, race-condition

I am a bit confused if there is a data race for variable `k`. To my understanding, only one thread will execute the single construct but since `no wait` is asserted, threads will start executing the `for` construct immediately. Is `atomic` here enough to prevent any potential data race?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define Nthreads 8

void main()
{

int n =9, l,k =n,i,j;
k += n+1;

omp_set_num_threads(Nthreads);

  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(n, k) private(j)
  {
   #pragma omp single nowait
    {
    k = k+5;
    }
   #pragma omp for nowait
     for( i =0; i< n; i++)
     {
      #pragma omp atomic
       k +=n+i+1;
     }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Having `atomic` in both worksharing constructs should suffice. You may also explicitly use `atomic update` to make your intent clearer to the reader.

Comment: Do you mean I should add `atomic` inside `single` construct as well?

Comment: He means using an `atomic` in both places ( `single` and `for` ) as well as  explicitly specifying the `update` atomic clause which is now implicitly used at the atomic synchronization construct. Being explicit is a matter of preference though, it will not change the output of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code expresses your intended algorithm correctly, it almost is. As you were probably suspecting yourself, you need to protect k' s update in the single region as well.

j is an unused variable, I do not know if you simply forgot to delete it or you were trying to implement sth else.

I would have used a reduction clause for k in the for loop instead of using a synchronization construct. I do not know if it would have been better or faster though.

Comment: What about the `k` inside `single`, doesn't it need atomic as well?

Comment: Yes it does, of course. An omp single region is only executed by one thread, however the other threads may be already executing the line where k is also updated therefore there you do need to use a critical sections in the single section as well.

edit: changed my WRONG answer. I am terribly sorry about that.